# Errors in defining variables after forward function

Tags: c++

I'm still fairly new to C++ programming in c++ but I keep getting errors that the variables are not declared and no matching function call. The main goal is to discern space between x and y variables.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

struct Points
{
  float x, y;
};

float calcDistance(struct Point *num1, struct Point *num2)
{
float x_portion, y_portion

(x2 - x1)^2
x_portion = pow((num2->x - num1->x),2);

(y2 - y1)^2 
y_portion = pow((num2->y - num1->y),2);

return sqrt(x_portion, y_portion)
}

int main()
{
Point num1;
Point num2;
float calcDistance = 0;

cout << "Enter x and y coordinate for the first point: ";
cin >> num1.x >> num1.y;

cout << "Enter the x coordinate of the second point: ";
cin >> num2.x >> num2.y;

cout << "The distance between x and y is " << calcDistance(&num1, &num2) << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Your struct is called Points with an s, but you use it as Point?

Comment: And `(x2 - x1)^2` should probably be a comment?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use the `struct` prefix when declaring variables, parameters or return types.

Comment: Prefer to pass by `const` reference rather than pointers.  A pointer can point *anywhere* and there is not an easy way to detect if they are pointing to the valid variable or not.

Comment: Also, `x * x` is more efficient than using `pow(x, 2)`.  Minimally, you eliminate the overhead of a function call.

Comment: Note:  all forms of [`sqrt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) use one parameter, not two.  You really don't want to use the comma operator here, because it gets evaluated before the function call (thus only calling `sqrt(y)`).  And the `sqrt` function does not modify its parameters.

Comment: Your [*distance formula*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/hs-geo-analytic-geometry/hs-geo-distance-and-midpoints/a/distance-formula) is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet showing points and calculating the distance between them:

```
struct Point2d
{
    float x;
    float y;

    float distance_to(const Point2d& other) const
    {
        const float x_dist = x - other.x;
        const float y_dist = y - other.y;
        const float x_squared = x_dist * x_dist;
        const float y_squared = y_dist * y_dist;
        return sqrt(x_squared + y_squared);
    }
};
```

You could use it like this:

```
Point2d a{3,4};
Point2d b{6,8};
float distance = a.distance_to(b);
```

You may want to overload `operator-` instead of using a method.

If you are not accustomed to methods in a structure, you could make it free standing:

```
float distance_between(const Point2d& a, const Point2d& b)
{
    const float x_dist = a.x - b.x;
    const float y_dist = a.y - b.y;
    const float x_squared = x_dist * x_dist;
    const float y_squared = y_dist * y_dist;
    return sqrt(x_squared + y_squared);
}
```

I prefer to use `const` temporary variables, as it allows a debugger to show the interim values.  Also, the compiler will optimize them out (at higher optimization settings).

Comment: BTW, the compiler is complaining about your `(x2 - x1)^2` and `(y2 - y1)^2` since `x1, x2, y1, and y2` are not defined.  Make it a comment (prefix with `//`).